# Map JsonArray to List<Pojo> using Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I need to convert a Json array represented as String to `List<Pojo>` using Jackson's ObjectMapper.

Here is what I did which doesn't really work:

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(String jsonString, Class<T> clazzType) {

    try {
      List<T> list = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<T>>() {});

      return list;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }
```

It returns an object with an internal list but doesn't really build the expected list of Pojos. I saw some attempts to use Reflection but I'm trying to keep it pure Jackson.

Any idea??

Comment: You shouldn't need reflection. You might need to make sure the variables in the POJO are basic types - or, if another type, that the other type is comprised of basic types, and so on. Personally, I've had better luck with Gson: Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject obj  = gson.fromJson(reader, MyObject.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TypeFactory to create a CollectionLikeType.
For example like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

CollectionLikeType collectionLikeType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory()
    .constructCollectionLikeType(List.class, String.class);

List<String> o = objectMapper.readValue("[\"hello\"]", collectionLikeType);

assertEquals(o, List.of("hello"));
```